# Batch (windows) ¿Cómo pongo un IF en otro IF?

Tags: batch

Necesito colocar un `If` dentro de otro `if`.

Cuando se cumpla un IF **(If1)** que haga algo **(cosa1)**, y si se cumple el primer if **(if1)** que se habilite el otro **(if2)** y luego si se cumple el del otro if **(cosa1),** se cumpla otra cosa **(cosa2)** en el otro if **(if2)**

Espero que se entienda, he intentado colocarlo dentro de paréntesis, pero no me deja, tal vez hay alguna cosa como el Do o Else, no me sé explicar.

---

```
  rem Sacar un dígito de %random%
  echo %random:~-1%
  rem if1---------------- cosa1 -------- if2-------------------cosa2 
  if %random:~-1%==5 set var1=encendido if %var1%==encendido set var2=encendido
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que poniéndolo de esta forma te solucionaría el problema. Así te debería dejar ejecutar los condicionales

```
rem Sacar un dígito de %random%
echo %random:~-1%
rem if1---------------- cosa1 -------- if2-------------------cosa2 

if %random:~-1%==5 (
  set var1=encendido

  if %var1%==encendido (
    set var2=encendido
  )
)
```